# Where to start sql query

Tags: sql, oracle, join, oracle11g

Here's what Im trying to do:
Display, by company, the company name, contact name and phone number for any payer who has no insureds.
I have no idea where to start.........

```
SELECT PAYER.COMPANY_NAME, CONTACT_NAME, PHONE_NUM
FROM PAYER
JOIN PLAN ON PAYER.PAYER_ID = PLAN.PAYER_ID
JOIN POLICY ON PLAN.POLICY_ID =POLICY.POLICY_ID
JOIN INSURED ON POLICY.POLICY_ID = INSURED.POLICY_ID
JOIN MORTAL ON INSURED.MORTAL_ID = MORTAL.MORTAL_ID
```

Where do I even start?

The erd:
[image: ERD]

Comment: "I have no idea where to start........" Maybe you should start by learning what a database is, what constraints are, and what sql is ?

Comment: I have been in a DB classes for a year now, Ive never seen this though. Sarcasm isnt needed. Have a good one.

Comment: JOIN has nothing to do here, consider the WHERE statement with a more improved FROM

Comment: No, I cant, unforunately. the first DB class was all theory, this one, is an online class. Yes it does seem simple, and when I figure it out, Ill likely feel dumb for not seeing the obvious......I dont understand import/export, this is a basic sql Class, at the 100 level, not a far more advanced (200 or above level) class that deals with the specialized sections.

Comment: JOIN has nothing to do here, consider the WHERE statement with a more improved FROM................looking at that now, please post as an answer instead of a comment so I can click your 'tick up'

Comment: but i've followed you by posting an answer ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have Oracle so I can't test what I'm about to post but look at the concept more than the syntax.  By using an outer join on the insured table, records will still be returned when there is no match but the value of any column you reference in the insured table will be NULL.  So, by using a WHERE clause that looks for a NULL value you are essentially doing what you want.

```
SELECT PAYER.COMPANY_NAME, PAYER.CONTACT_NAME, PAYER.PHONE_NUM 
FROM PAYER 
JOIN PLAN ON PLAN.PAYER_ID = PAYER.PAYER_ID 
JOIN POLICY ON POLICY.PLAN_ID = PLAN.PLAN_ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN INSURED ON INSURED.POLICY_ID = POLICY.POLICY_ID 
WHERE 
INSURED.POLICY_ID IS NULL
```

Here's something you need to consider, though.  Can a payer have no plans?  Can a plan have no policies?  In either of those cases, they will be no insured but you would have to expand upon this concept to cover those conditions.

Comment: Thanks, Thats the closest I can get, but still says 'no rows selected' I do believe a payer, since they are a payer, cannot have no plans, just nobody subscribing to the available plan, if that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your scheme, i think the JOIN statement has nothing to do here.
I would suggest to consider the WHERE statement with a more improved FROM statement.

I would like to be more useful but i have not enough power to build your database from scratch in my Oracle server : an export of your database will help a lot to definitively solve your problem